# How do I make conditional ligatures in Fontforge?

Tags: font-forge

Edit: I'm not sure what I did wrong last time I did this, but I tried it again recently and it worked perfectly.

I'm working on a Hebrew font and I want to make a conditional ligature that only shows up after certain letters. This ligature has its own unicode encoding so I though that [this](https://fontforge.github.io/editexample6-5.html) tutorial will be my savior as it's dealing with the same situation (but in Greek). I followed it step by step and I cannot seem to get the ligature to work at all. I don't know what I'm missing.

I also want to have an alternative ligature of the same letters which is not tied to any unicode encoding and would also be contextual. Would anyone know how to do this?